# Search for Facebook public events

Tags: facebook, events, search, facebook-graph-api, public

from the facebook documentation I know that

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event
```

will perform a search of the word "conference" in the name and description of all public events.

is it possible to search for ALL the events without specifying the "query" parameter? Basically I don't want to limit the search to a keyword, I want to get ALL the public events (of course I will limit the research using the location field).

Also is there any list of possible categories I can use for searching between events? Using query sets a limitation in particular for the language (in different countries I have to search for different keywords,instead with a category I would fix this problem).

thanks a lot

Claus

Comment: I think you accidentally a search term

Comment: can you tell us how you fixed it? Thanks

Comment: @MrBr use a * like this ... facebook.com/search?q=*&type=event this will display all events

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `q` (query) parameter, but you can use the `fields` parameter to specify the fields in which you're searching. You may be able to achieve what you're trying to do by using this parameter.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching for more info.

Comment: It looks strange it's not possible to filter the events using a category.Let's say I have to look for a concert: my query string would be "concert" in english and should be "concerto" in italian. It would be much easier if a generic category TYPE_CONCERT would be provided making it language independent. Do you think so?

Comment: Sure, that would be handy, but it's not how the API works right now.